# PayPal Patch Payee after approval before capture

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

In the PayPal documentation they state that you can update the payee email address after an order has been created

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_patch

However, if I try it by sending the following JSON to their API

```
 {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/payee",
        "value": {
            "email_address": "a-sandbox-business-account@business.example.com"
        }
    }
```

I get told that the payee is not patchable

```
{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":
     [{"field":"path",
       "value":"/purchase_units/0/payee",
       "location":"body",
       "issue":"NOT_PATCHABLE",
       "description":"Cannot be patched."
     }] 
 ... }
```

After struggling quite a bit with the PayPal integration I'm too invested to give up at this point! Any ideas on how I should go about this? I've also tried changing the parameter name from `email_address` to `email` and setting `value` directly to the email address but neither are working.  Do I need to replace the complete purchase_unit or maybe constructed my JSON badly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use standard JSON patch syntax to patch the value directly

```json
[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/payee/email_address",
    "value": "receiveremail@somedomain.com"
  }
]
```

Note that only a payee email_address can be patched; a merchant_id (if set instead) cannot be patched.

Comment: Thank you, I'd upvote this more than once if I could!